# Eyeball going crazy in a Cockapoo

Tags: dogs, health

I adopted a [Cockapoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockapoo) (not a F1 generation) puppy of 9 weeks old yesterday. He seemed very healthy and we saw the documents from the previous visit in the veterinary the breeder did, stating the dog is healthy (although had fleas).

Today, the puppy's left eyeball is very clearly not centered. Here is a picture

[image]

The breeder said he was in good health. I just sent him the picture but he hasn't answered yet. I also tried to contact the vet but the clinic is currently closed.

Can you give me some advice? What might likely be going on?

Comment: You need to got to the vet immediately!

Comment: the question is over two years old can you give an update on the result.you have edited your question saying the vet is closed after two years.

Comment: @trondhansen Thanks for your concern. The dog is doing very well. He is in good physical and mental health. I have recently opened [this post](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/22192/growing-black-stain-in-a-dogs-lower-eyelid) to ask about another potential eye concern. We ended up finding a vet clinic in town we went too. If I remember correctly, the vet gave him  antibiotic and his eye went back to normal in less than 12 hours. I remember trying to ask more questions but the vet could not give me much info about what might have been the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be several things. All of them mean that you need to take the dog to the vet immediately. This is not a problem that could easily be solved on here. It could be nerve damage or something even more serious. http://healthypets.mercola.com/sites/healthypets/archive/2015/04/22/5-diseases-causing-dog-blue-eyes.aspx.